# Regex: Identify all lines with a string that doesn't have a specific character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some text representing a list of email addresses where I would like to regex search for the lines that are missing a `@` in the email address.

For example:

```
email: foo@bar.com
email: baz.com
email: blah blah blah
name: Steve
```

I want `email: baz.com` and `email: blah blah blah` to be captured.

I know that I can use:

`(email: ".*")$` to capture all the lines with email in it.

Is there any way to further narrow down .* with a negative lookahead to exclude those with `@` already in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `/^email: [^@]*$/` to match a string that starts with `email:` then consists only of characters that aren't `@`.

Comment: When I try it on a test string at https://regex101.com/, it appears to not match at all if a single @ is anywhere in the text. How can I capture each of the lines as a separate match?